# How do find the .app file in Xcode 9.3.1

Tags: automation, appium, appium-ios, xcode9.3

Ok,

I've spent a few hours trying to find an answer to this question and had no luck what so ever.

I am creating an appium automated test using xcode Version 9.3.1 I need to locate the .app file so I can add it to my desired capabilities and I cant find it in any folder.

Breaking it this down in the most basic fashion, how do I locate the .app file so I can add it to my ios appium automated testing?

Out of curiousity would I need to use something like homebrew to locate it?

Or can I find from a specific menu in xcode?

Answer (score 1):

*Xcode* -> *Preferences* -> *Locations*

[image: Press button to open folder in Finder]

Press the button to open folder in *Finder*

Here you need to find project build folder, open it and search sub folders with `Debug-iphonesimulator` name, you should fine build file there.

The full path might look like:

`/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Project name>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator`

Answer (score 0):

By default Xcode stores the derived data for all projects in a single shared folder under your home directory at the following location:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

From Xcode 6, you can access or change derived data location from Preferences -> Locations Tab

but you can setup in xcode:

> File-> Project Setting

locate "Derived data:"

here is how to setup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVVRsR9XenQ

Answer (score 0):

Seriously thank you so much for all your help.  I really appreciated it so much.  You've all been a bunch of legends.   I was able to solve this problem and and I want help save someone 3 days of trouble.

Finding the .**app file is a HIDDEN FILE **

Basically there are number of ways to find the .app file in this version of Xcode.

1. You can find the .app by using your search bar on the mac. Also,  you can find the .app would be in this directory

**users/(YourMacAccount)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UICatalog-.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/(appname).app**

to reveal the hidden files type **cmd>shift>.**

If you still can't find it (Which is what happened to me). Then:

2. Click the show in finder icon (the one shaped like a file) in xcode

[This is where you can find it in xcode 9.3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56n82.png)